# cppcheck reports "Redundant code: Found a statement that begins with numeric constant" for a 'using' statement

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, cppcheck

Understanding that this is not a ton of context, I have this line:

```
using GridType = Grid<boost::optional<float>, 2>;
```

for which cppcheck says:

```
Redundant code: Found a statement that begins with numeric constant.
```

I would think "false positive", but usually these analysis tools are smarter than me, so I wanted to check if anyone can think of why a statement like this could be interpreted like that by the analyzer?

I'm using cppcheck 1.61 on a Ubuntu system.

Comment: You should mention your cppcheck version (and maybe the platform you are running it on).

Comment: @JesperJuhl Added version to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cppcheck is largely based on pattern matching and is not too smart / quite shallow at times. It *does* find a bunch of nice stuff but also has a *lot* of false positives. I'd say this is a false positive where cppchecks simple mind got confused.

Also; version 1.61 is a bit old. Have you tested the latest 1.74 to see if it is more clever here? 
(It's quite simple to build from source if it is not in your distributions repository)

Comment: 1.74 and 1.73 take SUPER long (many hours, almost like they hang) on Red Hat 4.8.3-9 (it's an AWS instance). 1.61 only takes a couple of minutes. I'm going to keep going backwards down the version list and see when it works better. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: No idea. 1.74 run in tens of minutes on the codebase I work on (~700.000 lines of C++).

Comment: It works fine with 1.70, is very slow but not as slow as higher versions with 1.71, is crazy slow with 1.72. I guess I'll stick with 1.70...? :)

Comment: Dang, I just saw 1.75 was release but it still essentially hangs on some of my files :(